# Define equality of xml

Tags: xml, haskell

Is there a way to define equality on Xml statements such that these three are the same (ignoring whitespaces and arguments and tags order)?

1:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```

2:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
</project>
```

3:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
</project>
```

For example, [xml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-1.3.12) isn't helpful because there is no `Eq` instance on [`Content`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml/1.3.12/doc/html/Text-XML-Light-Types.html#t%3aContent).

Also, [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.0.3) is not usable too, because [`Element`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml-conduit/1.0.3/doc/html/Text-XML.html#t%3aElement) contains all node elements in `List`. Also it's sensitive to whitespaces.

There are many libraries to work with `xml` including `HXT` but It's hard to find something usable.

Comment: Is the answer : 'yes'?  Perhaps I don't understand your question - what do you mean by define?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I define equality on Xml statements such that these three are the same?"?

Comment: @AndrewC, yes. There are many libraries in HXT but I can't find a method to normalizing xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the XML into some structure similar to:

```
data Tree = TreeNode (Set Tree) | LeafNode String deriving Eq
```

This reduces the problem to equality on sets and strings.

Comment: ..or even problem-specific datatypes like `data Project = Project {modelVersion :: Version, url::URL, groupID::String} deriving Eq`, using a cleverer parser

Answer (score 0):

Most definitions of equality (for example the XPath deep-equals() function) treat order of elements as significant. Saxon has a parameterized function saxon:deep-equals() but even that has no option to ignore element order - though it does have an option to ignore whitespace, so your (2) and (3) would be equal. You will need to write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's no `Eq` instance on [`Content`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml/1.3.12/doc/html/Text-XML-Light-Types.html#t%3aContent) in [xml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-1.3.12) because the definition of equality is domain-specific. In your application, order doesn't matter and there aren't repetitions, but someone else might use them to list commands to perform on some emulator.

This shouldn't stop you, though. You can add instances to imported data structures. In `Text.XML.Light.Types` we see that

```
 data CData    = CData {
              cdVerbatim  :: CDataKind,
              cdData      :: String,
              cdLine      :: Maybe Line
            }
```

so we can define

```
instance Eq CData where
   CData v d l == CData v' d' l' = and [v==v',d==d',l==l']
```

(I think this is uglier than `cd==cd' = cdVerbatim cd == cdVerbatim cd' && ....` but you'll at least get a compiler error if a later revision of xml adds constructors.)

You can do the same sort of definition for `Content`, but `Element` is where you can implement order-doesn't-matter with

```
instance Eq Element where
   Element n as cs l == Element n' as' cs' l' = and 
           [n==n',
            as==as',
            all (`elem` cs) cs',
            all (`elem` cs') cs,
            l==l']
```

You can add whitespace removal to the `Eq` instances you make, but not to the other data types. If you need to revise them, you can define your own `same` function and use it instead of `==` in your `Eq` instances.

I'm a little worried that `CData` is a bit thorny, and there might be different ways of representing the same string, so just checking the `cdData` String might not be enough; you might need to convert all `CDdata` to use the same `CDataKind` or something. On the other hand, if your xml is machine generated, it might all be the same anyway.